# Limit Law Proof

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I want to prove the limit law 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} [a_n -b_n] =  \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$$

Start supposing $\epsilon > 0$. Since $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=L $ Where $L$ is the limit, there is some $M_1 \in \mathbb N$ with $n\geq M_1$implying $\lvert a_n -L\rvert < ???$

I am not sure what to make $\epsilon$ in this case. Once I know what to make $\epsilon$ I can continue and set up $b_n$ and solve.

Comment: For both $a_n$ and $b_n$, take $\epsilon = \epsilon/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$|(a_n-b_n)-(L_1-L_2)|=|(a_n-L_1)+(-b_n+L_2)|\leq |a_n-L_1|+|b_n-L_2|$$

And for every $\epsilon$, you can find an $M$ such that for $n>M$ **both** $|a_n-L_1|$ and $|b_n-L_2|$ are less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, right?

Comment: So then I would continue my proof, there is some $M_2 \in \mathbb N$ with $n\geq M_2$implying $\lvert b_n -L_2\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ Let M be the larger of $M_1$ and $M_2$. Hence if $n \geq M$ then $n \geq M_1$ and $n \geq M_2$ so now $\lvert a_n-L_1\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\lvert b_n -L_2\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ So $\lvert (a_n-b_n)-(L_1-L_2)\rvert$ Is this the start?

Comment: Yeah! That's correct

Comment: I have continued on and now have that $\lvert a_n-b_n-L_1+L_2 \rvert = \rvert a_n-L_1-b_n+L_2 \rvert = \lvert (a_n-L_1)-1(b_n-L_2)\rvert \leq \lvert a_n-L_1 \rvert - \lvert b_n-L_2\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{2} = 0$ ?? But this isn't what we wanted. Could you help with where I went wrong

Comment: It's supposed to be a $+$ and not a $-$

Comment: I see how that would give me $\epsilon$ but I don't have a + there?

Comment: Because $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$, here $a=a_n-L_1, b=-b_n+L_2$

Comment: I feel like even if I do that I still end up with a negative since I pull a -1 from the $-b_n+L_2$?

Comment: But the thing is that $|-x|=|x|$ so you actually cancel the negative sign